# Android device to PC, file transfer by Socket connection

Tags: java, android, sockets, ip-address, serversocket

I'm transferring file from an Android emulator to a PC server through a Java application. The code on my client-side application is...

```
File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/sample.mp4"); //create file instance
client = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 4444);
byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) file.length()]; //create a byte array to file

fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream); 

bufferedInputStream.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length); //read the file

outputStream = client.getOutputStream();

outputStream.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length); //write file to the output stream byte by byte
outputStream.flush();
bufferedInputStream.close();
outputStream.close();
client.close();
```

However, when I run it on the Android device itself, the application won't work. I think I should replace "10.0.2.2" with some other value (i.e.: IP address of my PC server). What value should I put there?

Comment: Define "won't work". Give us exceptions, errors, stack traces, tell us what's wrong.

Comment: I'm not seeing any relevant exceptions, errors, etc on Logcat. The client application just can't connect to the server.

Comment: Assuming your device is connected to the same network (you say you're using the emulator so this shouldn't be a problem) then yes, you need your server's IP address in there. I'd expect for anything else to throw an `IOException` or similar if it were not connecting. One thing I notice is that you create a new `byte` array with the size of the file length, that's not going to play nicely with large files given how much memory it's going to take.